# How to fix blank input from variable into mysqli datebase?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am building one CMS sistem in PHP and in one segmet in admin area where I want to add input into mysql database I have a problem. Problem is that when I store users input into variable and put it into query the query insert blank space. But when I put the raw input into query it is working.

Here are the query with variable that to not work:

```html
 <?php
                         if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                           
                           $cat_title = $_POST['cat_title'];

                           if($cat_title = "" || empty($cat_title)){

                            echo "This field shoudl not be empty";

                           }else{
                               
                            $query = "INSERT INTO categories(cat_title) ";
                            $query .= "VALUE('{$cat_title}')";

                            echo $query; 

                            //$create_category_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                            /*if(!$create_category_query){
                              die("FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
                            }*/
                               

                           }

                         }


                        ?>
```

End here is the code that work:

```html
 <?php
                         if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                           
                           $cat_title = $_POST['cat_title'];

                           if($cat_title = "" || empty($cat_title)){

                            echo "This field shoudl not be empty";

                           }else{
                               
                            $query = "INSERT INTO categories(cat_title) ";
                            $query .= "VALUE('{$_POST['cat_title']}') ";

                           echo $query;

                            //$create_category_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                            /*if(!$create_category_query){
                              die("FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
                            }*/
                               

                           }

                         }


                        ?>
```

Comment: what get its output echo $cat_title;

Comment: try with $query = "INSERT INTO categories(cat_title) VALUES('$cat_title')";

Comment: The "echo $cat_title" is the mistake that sholud be "echo $query;". It displays line of query that is send. P.S. I tried the "VALUES('$cat_title')"; but it do not work. I currently use the raw post input but I would to figure out whay my variable in which is store that input pased blank input into database.

Comment: what it output echo  $cat_title = $_POST['cat_title'];

Comment: This is a simply typographical error. Please see the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if($cat_title = "" || empty($cat_title)){
       echo "This field shoudl not be empty";
   }else{   
      $query = "INSERT INTO categories(cat_title) ";
      $query .= "VALUE('{$cat_title}')";
```

Let's go through this from the top:

```
if ($cat_title = "" || ... )
```

This is only `=` which is an [**assignment operator**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) rather than the correct `==` which is a [**comparison operator**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) . What this is doing is *setting* `$cat_title`s value to be "".

Then later in your code, you are *inserting* `$cat_title`

## How to solve?

Replace your `if ($cat_title = ""`  with `if ($cat_title == ""`

> *NOTE:* The correct format should actually be `===` whereby this checks both the *value* and the *type* of the data (example: `if ($cat_title === "horse"`).

Infact, you can remove it entirely as the `empty` function does exactly the same thing. You can possibly add a [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function for clearing out whitespace, too

Therefore:

```
if(empty(trim($cat_title))){
  echo "This field should not be empty";
} else {
```

Comment: Thank you very much when I set my if condiditon to "==" it is work as it sholud. Once time thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For comparison `==` should be used. In your code I think by mistake single equals is used to check `$cat_title = ""`. Change is to `$cat_title == ""` and it should fix the problem.

```
$cat_title = "" this will set the variable to blank which is why you are getting empty value at the time of `INSERT`.

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $cat_title = $_POST['cat_title'];

    if($cat_title == "" || empty($cat_title)){

        echo "This field shoudl not be empty";

    }else{

        $query = "INSERT INTO categories(cat_title) ";
        $query .= "VALUE('{$_POST['cat_title']}') ";

        echo $query;

        //$create_category_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        /*if(!$create_category_query){
          die("FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
        }*/

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @Martin agree :)